# Associated simple products not showing in configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product, data-migration, configurable-swatches

In my magento2.1.5 (migrated from magento1.9) store, some configurable products are not showing any associated simple product in both admin and front-end. I need to set the simple products again in admin and then it is working good. This behavior is repeating in products that are migrated from magento1.9.

Strange thing is, when I get the children of that configurable product using the code below, it is not showing me the child products.

```
$children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
```

It looks like the simple products are associated but somehow Magento is not able to render this.

I also checked the values in the database and for most products having an issue, the value of "has_options" and "required_options" is set to 0. Changing it to 1 doesn't work for me.

These products were working fine earlier and are working fine on my older staging deployments. Can anyone please tell me what is the issue?

Comment: have you reindexed the catalog since importing?

Comment: as the issue is with association of products, try importing them once. Which tool you are using for migration ?

As @Eirik suggested, try re-indexing once if you didn't do till now.

Comment: @Eirik yes a lot of times. Also as I said it was working good 2 weeks ago but now products are not showing up with their associated children and swatches.